# Google Workspace Add-on error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringInputs' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm trying to create a Google Workspace Add-on, but keep getting this error when trying to access the input values of my first card:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringInputs' of undefined`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is my first attempt at a GWAO, and I'm not a coder, so I'm assuming it's something silly.

Background on what the app is supposed to do:

Get the text input and apply it to the company email address.
Get the selected dropdown input and get the associated calendar ID.
Get the date inputs and add the email to all of the events within the date range on the selected calendar.

Here's the code - some details are replaced with placeholders:

```
function cardHomepage() {
    let cardHeader1 = CardService.newCardHeader()
        .setTitle('Welcome to the training scheduler!')
        .setSubtitle('Select what you\'d like to do')
        .setImageUrl(
            '<IMAGE_URL>'
        )
        .setImageStyle(CardService.ImageStyle.CIRCLE);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button1Action1 = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('addAllCard');

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button1 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Add someone to all trainings')
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT)
        .setOnClickAction(cardSection1ButtonList1Button1Action1);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button2Action1 = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('TODO');

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button2 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Add someone to one training')
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT)
        .setOnClickAction(cardSection1ButtonList1Button2Action1);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button3Action1 = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('TODO');

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button3 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Remove someone from all trainings')
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT)
        .setOnClickAction(cardSection1ButtonList1Button3Action1);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button4Action1 = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('TODO');

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button4 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Remove someone from one training')
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT)
        .setOnClickAction(cardSection1ButtonList1Button4Action1);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1 = CardService.newButtonSet()
        .addButton(cardSection1ButtonList1Button1)
        .addButton(cardSection1ButtonList1Button2)
        .addButton(cardSection1ButtonList1Button3)
        .addButton(cardSection1ButtonList1Button4);

    let cardSection1 = CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(cardSection1ButtonList1);

    let card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setHeader(cardHeader1)
        .addSection(cardSection1)
        .build();
    return card;
}



// Add to all card
function addAllCard() {

    let cardHeader1 = CardService.newCardHeader()
        .setTitle('Add to all')
        .setSubtitle('Add someone to all trainings')
        .setImageUrl(
            '<IMAGE_URL>'
        )
        .setImageStyle(CardService.ImageStyle.SQUARE);

    let cardSection1TextInput1 = CardService.newTextInput()
        .setFieldName('text')
        .setTitle('LDAP')
        .setMultiline(false);

    let cardSection1SelectionInput1 = CardService.newSelectionInput()
        .setFieldName('trainCal')
        .setTitle('Training calendar to use')
        .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
        .addItem('CS Trainings', '<CALENDAR_ID>', false)
        .addItem('PL Trainings', '<CALENDAR_ID>', false)
        .addItem('Test Cal', '<CALENDAR_ID>', false);

    let cardSection1Divider1 = CardService.newDivider();

    let cardSection1DecoratedText1 = CardService.newDecoratedText()
        .setTopLabel('Date range')
        .setText(
            'Select the date range for which to add the person to trainings.')
        .setWrapText(true);

    let cardSection1DatePicker1 = CardService.newDatePicker()
        .setFieldName('startDate')
        .setTitle('Range start date');

    let cardSection1DatePicker2 = CardService.newDatePicker()
        .setFieldName('endDate')
        .setTitle('Range end date');

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button1Action1 = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('addToAllCS');

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button1 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Schedule')
        .setBackgroundColor('#1967d2ff')
        .setDisabled(false)
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
        .setOnClickAction(cardSection1ButtonList1Button1Action1);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1 = CardService.newButtonSet()
        .addButton(cardSection1ButtonList1Button1)

    let cardSection1 = CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(cardSection1TextInput1)
        .addWidget(cardSection1SelectionInput1)
        .addWidget(cardSection1Divider1)
        .addWidget(cardSection1DecoratedText1)
        .addWidget(cardSection1DatePicker1)
        .addWidget(cardSection1DatePicker2)
        .addWidget(cardSection1ButtonList1);

    let card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setHeader(cardHeader1)
        .addSection(cardSection1)
        .build();
    return card;
}


// Adds a user to all events on the chosen calendar within a specific timeframe.
function addToAllCS(e){ 

let ldap = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.text[""].stringInputs.value[0];
let calendar = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.trainCal[""].stringInputs.value;
let startD = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.startD[""].dateInput;
let endD = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.endD[""].dateInput;

let guestEmail = ldap + "@<COMPANY_DOMAIN>"; // Email address of the person to add.
let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar); // Calendar to use.
let calEvents = cal.getEvents(new Date(startD), new Date(endD)); // Gets all of the events within the timeframe.
console.log(calEvents.length); // Checks how many events it found.
for (var i = 0; i < calEvents.length; i++) { // Loops through all events and adds the person to each of them.
  let event = calEvents[i];
  event.addGuest(guestEmail);
}
}
```

Comment: The term commonEventObject is new to me.  Try removing it and just use e.formInputs.  But I have not built an addon in a while so things may have changed.

Comment: Which line in your code gives you this error?

Comment: This line is causing the error: let ldap = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.text[""].stringInputs.value[0];

Comment: Thanks, tried removing commonEventObject, but still received the same error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringInputs' of undefined [line: 216, function: addToAllCS, file: Code])

Comment: Why don't you log `JSON.stringify(e.commonEventObject.formInputs.text[""])` to see the content of the object?

Answer (score 2):

Spoke to a colleague who figured out that the [""] is no longer needed. This is what works instead:

```
    let ldap = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.text.stringInputs.value[0];
    let calendar = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.trainCal.stringInputs.value;
    let startD = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.startD.dateInput;
    let endD = e.commonEventObject.formInputs.endD.dateInput;
```